Is there any difference between a double salt and a mixture of two salts?
Is there any difference between a double salt and a mixture of two salts? If I were to take a aqueous mixture of two salts, say NaCl and KCl, and evaporate to dryness, how is it different from a double salt?
A google search on web came back with the following,

When two or more distinct salts are combined without undergoing a chemical reaction, a mixed salt is created. When two distinct salts interact chemically to create a new substance with a certain chemical formula, it is known as a double salt

What chemical reaction is being talked about here? Evaporating an equimolar mixture of iron(II) sulphate and ammonium sulphate gives Mohr's salt, a double salt. What chemical change do they undergo and how is it any different from mixing an aqueous solution of NaCl and KCl?

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/14950/boiling-solutions-with-two-salts https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/134484/which-salts-precipitate-from-a-potassium-sodium-chloride-sulfate-solution

"Chemical reaction" are empty words which mean nothing (in this particular case, that is). Formation of a double salt is exactly the same type of reaction as crystallization of one single salt. Whether to count it a chemical reaction or not is a matter of convenience (that is, about as unimportant as the last year's snow).
What's important is this: a double salt has two cations (or anions, or both) in one crystal structure, each sitting in its designated position. If you don't have that, you don't have a double salt.
Say, you mix $\ce{NaCl}$ and $\ce{FeS2}$ and grind them hard. You grind and grind and grind until you're tired, and then some, just in case. Now the mixture looks perfectly uniform to the naked eye... but it isn't. If you put it under the microscope, you'll see it still consists of tiny separate crystals of $\ce{NaCl}$ and $\ce{FeS2}$. This is not a double salt.
Then there is $\ce{KAl(SO4)2}$. Grind it or not, each crystal has the same composition and looks like this on the inside (though you'll need X-rays to see it, of course):

(source)
This is a double salt.
Then there are solid solutions, but that's a story for another day.
So it goes.

What if we don't physically grind the salts together, but instead evaporate a aqueous mixture of salts to dryness. Will that give us a double salt?
What I mean is, will i get a double salt if I were to add two salts to water, and evaporate it do dryness?

If you dissolve two salts and then evaporate the solution to dryness, then sometimes you'll get a double salt, and sometimes a solid solution, and sometimes a mixture of two solid salts that you've started with, and sometimes a mixture of two other solid salts (with cations switched). This is not a thing that can be deduced through logic alone. Chemistry is an experimental science, they say.

Definite proportions?

Ok, I think i understand it much better now. Here is what I think understood, correct me if I am wrong. Double Salt is when two or more salts form a single crystal, chemically interact with each other, like in Mohr Salt, where aqua ferrous ion is h-bonded to ammonium and sulphate ion. Such double salts arent formed by evaporating any two salts solutions. Some may give double salts, others may give a solid solution, where the constituent ions are spread homogenously but they arent themselves interacting chemically, and others yet may form two different salt crystals?

Basically yes, except I wouldn't say "chemically interact", for that's meaningless too. Sure, all cations are electrostatically attracted to all anions, which you may or may not call a chemical interaction (after all, much of chemistry is driven by it), but that's not what differentiates the systems which have double salts from those which don't.

To put it differently: the existence of $\ce{KAl(SO4)2}$ is not due to some mysterious attraction between $\rm K^+$ and $\rm Al^{3+}$ (there is most definitely no such thing), but due to the fact that the two just happen to pack nicely together with certain anions.

Saying it is a chemical reaction is very misleading.
Evaporation of mixture of salts not forming double/multiple salts leads to different crystals of each salt.
Double salts form crystals or generally particles combining ions of both salts. Like crystals of alums, formed from solution of potassium and aluminium (chromium(III), iron(III)) sulfate. The respective three latter ions can substitute each other in any ratio, so one can prepare a quadruple salt.
There is no difference while ions are in solution as all ions act independently.
In complex amorphous or microcrystalline substances, like chlorinated lime with calcium hydroxide, chloride and hypochlorite, it may be difficult to decide the case. But there were identified some double salts.
Wikipedia:

Commercial calcium hypochlorite consists of anhydrous $\ce{Ca(OCl)2}$, dibasic calcium hypochlorite $\ce{Ca3(OCl)2(OH)4}$ (also written as $\ce{Ca(OCl)2·2Ca(OH)2}$), and dibasic calcium chloride $\ce{Ca3Cl2(OH)4}$ (also written as $\ce{CaCl2·2Ca(OH)2}$).

